# VS Code Font Rendering on macbook pro retina with external monitor

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, rendering, resolution, dpi

I connected an external monitor to my macbook. (HP 24w)

On some editors, including vsc, I can not work on the external monitor because the resolution and font rendering is not perfect.

I have attached the two photos below to show the problem.

Can you advise me something?

Thank you.

- First photo: mb pro
- Second photo: hp 24w external monitor

[image: MacBo pro retina 2015]

[image: HP Monitor 24 full hd]

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me.

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode.helper CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```